# Is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continous functions converging to a continuous function locally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I$ be a closed and bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ a continuous function on a neighborhood of $I$. Suppose there is a sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous function converging pountwise to $f$ at each point of $I$.

1) Can we say that for $n>$ some $N$, the sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded?

2) If you cannot answer this question, vote to keep it on hold!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take $I=[0,1].$ Consider $f_n=n\chi_{(1/(n+1),1/n)}.$ These $f_n$ are not continuous, but they should give some intuition.